# Looking for a CoAP api/library for android/java?

Tags: java, android, iot, coap

Is there a api/library for CoAP that I can use on android side? I've been looking for one for sometime now but with no luck at all.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/cf-android/app/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/examples

Comment: Thanks for this @VVB

Comment: If it helps your then can I post it as an answer so you can up vote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://coap.technology/impls.html) you can find all coap implementations.
When i tried [Californium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium) a few months ago (version 18) it wasn't working on Android (but I suppose that now it works) and I used [ncoap](https://github.com/okleine/nCoAP) instead.